# How to only list files modified today in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

1. How would I list only the files modified today?
2. How would I `'scp'` the files updated today to another server?
3. How would I list files with modified date?

Comment: To handle your ultimate goal quicker and easier you might want to try `rsync`. It was made for that.

Answer (score 1):

first question:

```
find YOUR_DIR -type -f -mtime 0
```

second question:

```
for file in $(find DIR -type -f -mtime 0); do scp $file server:$file; done
```

third question:

```
ls -al YOUR_FILE
stat -c %y YOUR_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` is prone to expansion issues. Use `find -exec` or `xargs` instead. scp also fails to preserve attributes.

Thus, second question's answer:

`find DIR -type f -mtime 0 -exec rsync -Sav '{}' server: \; ; done`

(And it's also independent of ubuntu.)